# Can we learn ethical hacking from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

For a newbie like me to programming, I found no other site valuable and live other than Stack Overflow for acquiring skills, so I just want to ask: Can we? If not, any thoughts?

I understand the value of ethical hacking and for the same reason I want to learn it.

I know that the philosophy of Stack Overflow is to question and answer. Then why can't any expert show us the problem (common mistakes, show the issue and answer) and come up with a solution? If some other has a better thought in the way around, he will present the same.

Please post your valuable comments and **help me to understand** why it's not included yet ..than merely voting.

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

[Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

You can ask programming related questions while learning ethical hacking on SO.

You can ask ethical hacking related questions on:
https://security.stackexchange.com/

I shouldn't give suggestions about learning ethical hacking. But you can learn ethical hacking here:

1. http://www.ethicalhackingtraining.com/
2. http://www.iisecurity.in/training.html
3. http://nrupentheking.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 5):

What you can't do:

- Learn ethical hacking (too broad and vague)
- Learn about ethics (off-topic)
- Learn about hacking (too broad, probably controversial)

What you *can* do:

- Ask questions about code you're using in your study of ethical hacking
- If the question likely presents a controversial subject, indicate that it is more of an academic curiosity in wanting to know how the code/system works
- *Answer* questions which are related to the things you learn during your study of ethical hacking, thereby contributing your knowledge to the community and helping everybody improve their understanding of how the code/system works.

Many kind of questions are welcome here on Stack Overflow.  "How do I learn about ethical hacking" isn't one of them.  You can gain all kinds of technical knowledge which would contribute to your study of ethical hacking.  But this isn't the proper venue for an open discussion on the subject in general.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to learn ethical hacking, there are already good resources which exist specifically for that purpose. For example:

[www.hackthissite.org](http://www.hackthissite.org)